# Passing pointers to function does not return value

Tags: c++, pointers

In following case I get   NumRecPrinted = 0 , that is num is 0

```
int main()
{
    int demo(int *NumRecPrinted);
    int num = 0;
    demo(&num);
    cout << "NumRecPrinted=" << num;    <<<< Prints 0
    return 0;
}

int demo (int *NumRecPrinted)

{
    int no_of_records = 11;
    NumRecPrinted = &no_of_records;
}
```

Comment: You haven't changed the value of the int, you've assigned a new address to the pointer.  That should be `*NumRecPrinted = no_of_records;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning the address to the pointer, and not the value to the pointed-to. Try it like this instead

```
int demo (int *NumRecPrinted)
{
     int no_of_records = 11;
     *NumRecPrinted = no_of_records; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No!

```
*NumRecPrinted = no_of_records;
```

See "*" means "value of" and "&" means "address of". You want to change the "value of" NumRecPrinted, which is why the above works. What you did was to give NumRecPrinted the "address of" num_of_records.

Answer (score 2):

All you did was pointer the *local pointer-to-int* `NumRecPrinted` at a new integer inside the `demo` function.

You want to change the integer it points to, not change where it points.

```
*NumRecPrinted = no_of_records;
```

You can *see* in your version that you're taking the address of a local variable, and you know it isn't the address of that variable you care about, but its value.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the * = the value of and & = address of. So you were just assigning a new address to the pointer inside the method. You should:

```
*NumRecPrinted = no_of_records;
```

See this excellent tutorial on [Pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). E.g.:

```
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed by p1 = 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // value pointed by p2 = value pointed by p1
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed by p1 = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You want
    *NumRecPrinted = no_of_records;

That means, "set the thing NumRecPrinted points to to equal no_of_records".